# How to replace values in multidimensional array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to get a multidimensional array working, where the user string is filled in the cell. 
I have been searching for ways to update user values in the multidimensional array

```
  def createMultiArray(self,usrstrng,Itmval):
    #creates a multidimensional array, where usrstrng=user input, Itmval=width        
    ArrayMulti=[[" " for x in range(Itmval)]for x in range(Itmval)]

    # need to update user values, therefore accessing index to update values.
    for row in ArrayMulti:
        for index in range(len(row)):

            for Usrchr in usrstrng:
                row[index]= Usrchr
    print "This is updated array>>>",ArrayMulti
```

Input

```
  funs
```

current output that i am getting

```
  This is updated array>>> [['s', 's', 's'], ['s', 's', 's'], ['s', 's', 's']]
```

what i am looking for

```
  This is updated array>>> [['f', 'u', 'n'], ['s', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

the blank can be filled in with *

Comment: Why are you looping over `usrstrng` to replace the space character?

Comment: @James i was trying to replace each value of the cell with each character of the string

Comment: But once you replace, there will be no more spaces in the string and so subsequent calls to `replace` will do nothing.

Comment: @dbliss i have updated the original code in the current question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string.replace won't work, since it does not affect the original value.

```
>>> test = "hallo"
>>> test.replace("a", " ")
'h llo'
>>> test
'hallo'
```

Instead you need to access the list via the indexes:

```
for row in ArrayMulti:
    for index in range(len(row)):
        row[index] = "a"
```

<strike>If you provide a more precise question and add the output you want to achieve to the question, I can give you a more precise answer.</strike>

I scrapped the previous solution since it wasn't what you wanted

```
def UserMultiArray(usrstrng, Itmval):
    ArrayMulti=[[" " for x in range(Itmval)] for x in range(Itmval)]

    for index, char in enumerate(usrstrng):
        ArrayMulti[index//Itmval][index%Itmval] = char
    return ArrayMulti


>>> stack.UserMultiArray("funs", 3)
[['f', 'u', 'n'], ['s', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

This little trick uses the whole-number-division:

> [0, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4] // 3 -> 0, 0, 0, 1, 1

and the modulo operator(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

> [0, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4] % 3 -> 0, 1, 2, 0, 1

Comment: 's Arraymulti is a multidimensional array where i have initialized it with" " ...now i am using the for loop to put each value of the string in subsequent cell

Comment: The args were UserMultiArray("hallo", 5)

Comment: @dbliss thanks for the update the brief description of the code can be see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665750/updating-values-in-multidimensional-array

Comment: thanks it kinda helped, now how can you guide me like how can I get vacant cell at the end to be filled in with some symbols like ' * '

Answer (score 0):

This should work, only you need to move through your string as long as you move through the matrix, you only need to know how many characters you use in the previous iterations

```
offset = 0
for row in ArrayMulti:
    if len(usrstrng) > offset
        for index in range(len(row)):
            if len(usrstrng) == offset + index
                break
            row[index] = usrstrng[offset + index]
    else:
        break
    offset += len(row)
```

**EDIT**

you can also do this

```
[[usrstrng[i*Itmval + j] if len(urstring) > i*Itmval + j else ' ' for j in range(Itmval)] for i range(Itmval)]
```